# react-router with not-found-route on root

Tags: reactjs

I want to create an page not found (404) on root, but seems no luck.

using the example from [react-route](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md)

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>

        <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}>
          <Route name="message" path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
          <DefaultRoute handler={InboxStats}/>
        </Route>

        <Route name="calendar" handler={Calendar}/>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Dashboard}/>

    </Route>
);
```

the  `< DefaultRoute />`  will be displayed inside `App`, which will still display the link. I would like to see a not found page (404) by itself only. How would you achieve this?

ps. making `DefaultRoute` on the same level as the root `Route` would produce complain =(

any suggestion would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mapping you want, you can remove `name="main"` making it the default route:

```
<Route path="/" handler={Root}>
    <Route handler={Main}>
        <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}>
            <Route path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

Also this discussion [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/140), worth looking.

Comment: great! exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultRoute` and `NotFoundRoute` were removed in react-router 1.0.0.

To display a 404 page and preserve url (as `NotFoundRoute` did):

```
<Route path='*' component={My404Page} />
```

To display a 404 page but change the url (as `DefaultRoute` did):

```
<Route path='/404' component={My404Page} />
<Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `<NotFoundRoute>` handler:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>

  <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}>
      <Route name="message" path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
      <DefaultRoute handler={InboxStats}/>
   </Route>
  <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

See this [link](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/components/NotFoundRoute.md):

> When a parent's URL partially matches, but none of the children do, a
>   NotFoundRoute will be matched and its handler activated at any level
>   of your route hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for replying, I understand what you're staying. but in this case, App has top navigation (menu) and not found will be displayed under it in the route that I provided. How would you suggest a new route be if I want a not found page without top navigation (menu)

it seems like react-router-component has something like that. but what if I want to stick with react-router?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping you App component with a component that does not have that navigation menu?

Answer (score 0):

so here's what I end up doing:

I added a root which contains RouteHandler only (replaced {App} )

```
/not-found -> goes to not found page (because root has no menu)  
/main -> redirect to /main/inbox (main contains menu)  
/main/inbox -> goes to inbox view
/main/inbox/44 -> goes to message #44
```

Route setting looks something like this:

```
<Route path="/" handler={Root}>
    <Route name="main" handler={Main}>
        <Route name="inbox handler={Inbox}>
            <Route path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

my original intent was

```
/not-found -> goes to not found page (because root has no menu)   
/inbox -> goes to inbox view
/inbox/44 -> goes to message #44
```

because I kinda want to have menu as a master page and other pages can continue to use it.

guess I have to settle with this for now =(